# @Id annotation on getId() method catch an Exception on autoincrement column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I want to understand why when I insert an @Id annotation on the getId () method it throws an error on the auto increment ID column, this is the error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Converting `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): models.User

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): models.User
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:741)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:719)
    servlets.Authentication.doGet(Authentication.java:30)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): models.User
    org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:33)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:114)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53)
    org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:735)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:719)
    servlets.Authentication.doGet(Authentication.java:30)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

this is my model class:

```
package models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "cognome", nullable = false)
    private String cognome;
    @Column(name = "mail", nullable = false)
    private String mail;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "token", nullable = true)
    private String token;
    @Column(name = "dataCreazioneToken", nullable = true)
    private Date dataCreazioneToken;



    public User() {}

    public User(String nome, String cognome, String mail, String password) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getDataCreazioneToken() {
        return dataCreazioneToken;
    }

    public void setDataCreazioneToken(Date creazioneToken) {
        this.dataCreazioneToken = creazioneToken;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public void setId (int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

So if I remove the @Id annotation on the getId () method, the error will not be raised and the id is generated automatically. i can't understand why

Comment: [Access Strategies in JPA and Hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/access-strategies-in-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: You cannot mix and match annotations - by putting it on your property, it then ignores annotations on the field and so does not see the GeneratedValue annotation, and so requires you to manually assign IDs.